# Xcode 5 copy and paste

Tags: xcode, xcode5, osx-mavericks

I upgraded to OS X Mavericks and Xcode 5.0.1 but I am having problems copying and pasting from/to Xcode 5. I have not been able to find any information on the internet. Does anyone else have this problem?

Comment: Can you copy and paste to other apps in Mavericks?

Comment: @NikosM. Yes, I can copy and paste to other apps.

Comment: is this a problem only when using keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: @BradAllred Keyboard shortcuts and the context menu don't work

Comment: I believe my Xcode installation is completely broken. Interface builder isn't working correctly either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed this problem when working with programs that manipulate the general pasteboard `[NSPasteboard generalPasteboard]`, and restarting generally resolves the problem.

Comment: Restarting my computer did solve the problem but it keeps coming back. This never happened when I used Jumpcut but started happening once I installed Flycut. Now it keeps happening even with Flycut uninstalled.

Answer (score 1):

Restarting my computer fixed my problem.